# What number + 1 equals itself?

Tags: number-theory

Answer in numerical form.

The answer is not an integer.
The answer is in string form.
The answer is not my love life...

Comment: Is this really a puzzle?

Comment: It is confusing that "the answer is in string form" however you ask for an answer "in numerical form". Given this wording it appears that you are expecting the answer to be related to programming. In programming there is usually +ve infinity, -ve infinity and NaN. I'm guessing that "The answer is not my love life" is a joke to rule out NaN. My point is that if infinity is the answer that you are expecting then you've kinda mixed up programming and mathematics since infinity and NaN are values in programming however they aren't actually numbers. Even then @Rubio 's point still holds

Comment: @Adam NaN doesn't actually work, though, as it doesn't equal itself. +1 or not.

Comment: @JohnDvorak however as a string it does! It really depends on the interpretation. Even then we don't know whether the question was asked with the lack of this knowledge or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it

> Infinity ∞, because infinity + 1 = infinity

Comment: I hope not, because infinity is not a number.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Yeah you're right, but it also says the answer is not an integer.. I don't know

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain `isNaN(1/0) == true`

Comment: `[(1/0.0).is_a?(Numeric), (1/0.0).is_a?(Integer)] == [true, false]`

Comment: It is a number in some number systems.

Comment: @noedne Is addition relevantly defined in these number systems?

Comment: @Arnaud Mortier Of course.

Comment: @noedne Could you please indicate a reference to a paper or just name such a system?

Comment: The projective or affine reals.

Answer (score 4):

Some have expressed concerns whether infinity is a number. My proposal definitely is.

> In JavaScript notation:
>  `x = new Number(); x.value = 0; x.valueOf = function(){return this.value++}`
>  `x + 1 == x // true`