# computer programmer's maths puzzle

Tags: mathematics

A computer programmer looked at part of his code

```
x = x + 1;
```

and then thought what a strange equation that would be for a mathematician

$$x=x+1$$

The programmer asked some mathematicians if any number, $x$, would satisfy the mathematical version of the equation above.

Would it have been possible for one of the mathematicians to have suggested a number for $x$?

*Note about edit*
I have tried to edit to give a well defined question - or at least better defined than the original question.

Comment: Keep in mind that infinity is **not** a number

Comment: @adam maybe that should be an answer....

Comment: Oh sorry, I was having flashbacks to [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80790/what-number-1-equals-itself) which is nowhere near as defined as this one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What number + 1 equals itself?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80790/what-number-1-equals-itself)

Comment: @Rubio - I would value your opinion if the edit to this question has made it defined enough to warrant it being taken off hold.    If not it has been downvoted enough to just be deleted, but I don't want to just delete it if not necessary given the number of answers it has -I would value any thoughts you have about this.

Comment: @tom It perhaps should have been closed as a duplicate of the question in the comments - or perhaps the other way around, as arguably *this* question now has answers that cover additional possibilities than the other question did. The question itself has 3 issues: 1) assuming the intended answer is infinity, we have the issue that (other than in some narrow spaces) infinity isn’t “a number” and/or “plus 1” doesn’t make sense applied to it; 2) if you start looking for the kinds of spaces where infinity could work, [palsch’s answer](/a/89631) shows why it ends up being too broad and subjective.

Comment: Finally and most fatally, in my opinion, 3) [how is this a *puzzle*?](/80790#comment235847_80790) It seems more something to *recognize* than something to solve—that is, a trivia question more than a puzzle. Unless there is more to this than the answers to both questions have come remotely close to grasping, this isn’t a puzzle.  (And if you just posed it to see if someone could find an answer that works, rather than posing it as a puzzle designed to hint toward a solvable answer, then I submit to you that you’ve posed that speculative question in the wrong site altogether.).

Comment: The edit changes none of this. So to answer your comment, I don’t believe the edit has done anything to salvage the question from the deficiencies I’ve outlined.

Comment: @Rubio - many thanks for your helpful comments about this. - This makes me all the more sure that I should just delete the question, but then I feel bad for the people who have put the effort in to make answers. ... Do you agree that deletion is the best thing given the question is fatally flawed?  -- I appreciate you comments though for  carefully explaining why it is fatally flawed. Hopefully future questions I pose will be better.

Comment: @Rubio the only reason I can think of for keeping the question is as an example of a bad question, but if it is a bad question then it should probably just be deleted.

Comment: On the subject of my answer, I didn't put any effort into it, in fact before posting I was really conflicted over whether this question would likely be put on hold or just heavily downvoted so it doesn't bother me if you delete this or not. That said, all of the answers are practically rhyming off trivia except for palsch's so likely everyone agrees with me.

Comment: @tom You ... may not be *able* to delete, as it's already drawn answers. For some general advice, see my answer to [What should I do if I've made a mistake in my question?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6652), which covers this ground pretty well. For this question in particular, I was actually going to respond that even a flawed question can serve as a good example of what kind of things *do not* work well, so if nothing else, I think that's a fair disposition for it. Note too that I'm more than tempted to make the related question a duplicate of this one, which I may yet do.

Comment: @Rubio - thanks again for the guidance. So I won't try to delete it. I am, of course, happy for you to do whatever you think is best with this question as a moderator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a pretty open question to me. Some tries:

First, he asks you about your

> definition of a number

Whatever you answer, he may

> [tell you about some of his thoughts about what qualifies as a number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36289/is-infinity-a-number). If $\pm$ infinity qualifies as one, that would work for x.

Then of course there are

> number spaces like $\mod 1$ in which e.g. $0.5 \equiv 1.5 \mod 1$

If you don't really have a

> definition... I guess the mathematician would love to come up with something for you. For example just define that $x$ and $1$ should be "numbers", and $+$ means just ignoring all numbers after it. Then $x = x + 1$ would be true.

...but that's a pretty unusual thing to do. In real life I think I have already seen this:

> $1$ meaning "everything" in set theory and $+$ meaning merging sets (being used instead of $\cup$). Then if $x = 1$ you merge two identical sets which results in the same set $x$. So $x = x + 1$ would be true here. But then sadly I guess sets don't quality as numbers? It fit so well that I wanted to include it though.

Oh, another one:

> If you define $=$ as binding stronger than $+$ then technically, the *equation* $x = x$ is of course true for any number and the $+1$ can just be ignored

All of these approaches seem a bit cheet-y to me. I'd love to see a more elegant solution of this.

Comment: thanks for the great answer. It would be accepted, but the question is not so good and I am likely to delete it.

Comment: @tom That's ok. Would you mind telling what solution you personally had in mind before doing that?

Comment: sure no problem. For me the answer the computer scientist had in mind was infinity. I had not realized all the potential mathematical subtleties such as the answer in terms of set theory.

Answer (score 3):

Well...

> No such number exists that satisfies $x=x+1$. If $x=\infty$ then it is possible however $\infty$ is not a number.

Comment: "Keep in mind that infinity is not a number – Adam 25 mins ago" - Why did you post then?

Comment: @Duck wording of - "Could anyone suggest a number for x?"

Comment: "No such number exists that satisfies $x = x + 1$" Do you have a proof for that? Or is it just "obvious"?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bit too 'on the computer programming side' to be the mathematicians response, but still...

> What about $x=\frac{1}{9}$?
>  If $+$ is seen as the concatenation operation, then $x=0.\overline{1}=0.\overline{1}+1$.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling SE - sorry that the question is not so good and I am likely to delete. I think your answer is quite ingenious and would upvote it, but as I am going to delete the question there is no point in upvoting I'm afraid.  - Well done for using the format for hiding your answer! I hope that you enjoy Puzzling SE and consider answering other better questions.

Comment: ok, see the comments by the question, but this question probably won't be deleted, so I upvote for the nice answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer is (I think):

> When the computer sees the equals sign, it evaluates the expression to the right of the equal sign, then assigns the answer to that expression to the variable on the left side. It is not an equality but telling the computer to replace y with y+1. So y can be any number.

If this is wrong, please let me know, as I am not very good with programming and computer science.

Comment: I think that's true but not the "mathematical version of the equation" but more of an programmer's view on it.

Comment: @palsch Well, x could be any number if my answer is correct.

Comment: I think the question aimed at *not* defining the $=$ like a programmer since a programmer asks a mathematician about his point of view, not the other way around.

Comment: Actually to be honest "Could anyone suggest a number for x?" is fairly ambiguous so this could be an answer

Comment: What is the downvote for? I will delete my answer if you want...